# Validation using razor without submiting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my view I have following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "searchInvoiceForm", @class = "form-inline" }))
{

    @Html.Label("Numer faktury", new { @class = "margin-top-10" })
    @Html.TextBox("invNumber", "", new { @class = "input-sm form-control margin-right-10 margin-left-20", @type = "number", @min = "0" })
    ...
    <button id="searchForInvoicesButton" class="btn margin-top-10 margin-bottom-10">Szukaj</button>
}
```

So i want to use this "razor-style" validation like "@type = "number", @min = "0"", but my submit button in javascript is prevented from default action. I tried something like

```
var form = $('#searchInvoiceForm');
if (form.valid()) {
...
```

but it never seems to pass the validation. I have couple others textboxes in my form, but this is te only one required and with some limitation like number and minValue. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: What validation attributes do you have on your properties? `type = "number` and `min = "0"` have nothing to do with jquery validation - they are HTML-5 attributes (and there is no such thing as _"razor-style" validation_).

Comment: What I'm asking is is there a way to invoke this validation trigerred on submit button in standard form, but using jquery.

Comment: Not using `form.valid()` - that is associated with `jquery.validate.js`. If you want to use `form.valid()` then you need to add rules to the validator, and the easiest way to do that is to add validation attributes , for example a `RangeAttribute` on your property which will also give your server side validation (which is most important)

Comment: Take a look at the jQuery unobtrusive validation: [http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript)

Comment: Okay, thanks for help